# Incorrect number of bindings SQL

Tags: python, sql

I'm generating N random numbers between 0-100.  N relies on the amount of rows there is in table_1.  There's 200 rows.  I get 200 random numbers in a list returned.

I'm trying to insert these 200 numbers from the list as individual rows into table_2's random_number column.  There is no link between the random numbers and the 3 other columns in table_2.

```
 r = [random.randint(0,100) for rows in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1')]
 for r in rows:
       cursor.execute('UPDATE table_2 SET random_number = (?)', r)
```

This is what I currently have.  I get a

> ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current
>   statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied

error. I've seen other solutions where they ad (?, ) but it doesnt work.  I've also tried:

```
       r = [random.randint(0,100) for rows in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1')]
       r = str(r)

       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table_2 (random_number) VALUES (?)', [','.join(r)])
```

Which is running, but nothing is being inserted into the random_number column.

Comment: aren't you overwriting your `r` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue.  I noticed that it was splitting and saving integers to new rows on their own.

This is how I resolved it:

```
          rows = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1').fetchall()
          r_list = [random.randint(0,100) for row in rows]

          for i in xrange(0,len(rows)):
                       cursor.execute('UPDATE table_2 SET random_number=' + str(r_list[i]) + ' WHERE row_id = ' + str(rows[i][0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that rows is no longer in scope when you access it in your for loop, nor is it the list you'd want to iterate over.

If i understood correctly then you should change your script into something like this:

```
# generate random list
r_list = [random.randint(0,100) for rows in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1')]

# iterate over that list and insert
for r in r_list:
       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table_2 (random_number) VALUES (?)', r)
```

Comment: Also: `UPDATE` is the wrong operation, and even if it was not this will always update *all* rows in table_2 on each iteration.

Comment: @EmilVikström yeah i forgot to change that, i edited my answer with an insert

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm now getting the error: ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type.  Is this because it's expecting a int when r_list values are str?  I haven't specified a data type for the random_number column either

Comment: If I state that r_list is a str, it runs, however again, nothing is inserted into the column.

Comment: or does it not support values from a list?